# what is difference among '\', '\\', '\\\' when LIKE matching for float number?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-like, backslash

Using raw query, I tried to match with keyword in below column that name is 'desc' from test table.

```
desc 
The progress is above 93% or not
The progress is above 93.1% or not
The progress is above 93.15% or not
```

Using keyword '93%' to match only exact matching with 93% not included 93.1% or 93.15%

```
SELECT desc FROM test WHERE Replace(desc, ' ', '') LIKE '%93%%';
```

result as we can see all of three.

```
SELECT desc FROM test WHERE Replace(desc, ' ', '') LIKE '%93\%%';
```

result as we can see all of three.

```
SELECT desc FROM test WHERE Replace(desc, ' ', '') LIKE '%93\\%%';
```

this time, only 1 result I can get with exact matching.

```
SELECT desc FROM test WHERE Replace(desc, ' ', '') LIKE '%93\\\%%';
```

this one also same as `'\\'`

Please explain  the difference.

Comment: Numbers aren't text. `LIKE` doesn't apply to numbers. What you posted is *text*, not a floating-point number. In *some* countries, `93.5` can be handled as a percentage.

Comment: You're trying to match a complex text pattern. LIKE can't do that. You need a regular expression for this. SQL, the language, doesn't support regular expressions. Some databases like PostgreSQL offer regular expression methods BUT these can't take advantage of indexing. If you use a regex to find just ` 93%` you'd have to scan all rows in the table. That's very slow.

Comment: What are you trying to do? What is the *real* problem you want to solve? If you want to identify specific log entries, use a table schema that stores the data you want to filter in separate, indexed fields, eg a `Progress` field. Or use a separate table that tracks just the information you want, eg a `Jobs` or `JobHistory` table with a `progress` field. For modest amounts of data, you can log data as JSON or XML with distinct `progress` fields which you can extract using JSON functions. You may be able to create and index  a calculated column that exposes the `progress` value

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: the operator `similar to` is part of the SQL standard and does support regular expressions (although not completely compliant with the POSIX regex)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name and yet, most databases use `REGEXP_LIKE` even 20 years later. Looks like only PostgreSQL and Firebird support `SIMILAR TO` and even then [it looks to be a compromise doomed to failure](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10694/pattern-matching-with-like-similar-to-or-regular-expressions-in-postgresql). Which is .... a common theme with most SQL features. One could create a Crown-like soap opera for SQL. I suspect Codd, Date and Darwen [would even say](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Third_Manifesto) that  `compromise doomed to fail` is the guiding principle

Comment: None of your queries will even run as written, as `desc` is a reserved word.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos What I'm trying that it's brand matching. In keyword table, there are around 700 as hamburger(text), 90(number) 91.42%(percentage), vitaminC20%. When keyword matched with description column then get the brand as Mcdonals, Heinz. So I just want to know why 90% keyword can match with 90.1% 90.15% or 90\\%  can't

Answer (score 0):

The only explanation I have is that you are either using an ancient PostgreSQL version or that [`standard_conforming_strings`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/runtime-config-compatible.html#GUC-STANDARD-CONFORMING-STRINGS) is set to `off`.

You should then get a warning, unless you have set [`escape_string_warning`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/runtime-config-compatible.html#GUC-ESCAPE-STRING-WARNING) to `off`.

```
test=> SET standard_conforming_strings = off;
SET
test=> SELECT 'above 93.15% or not' LIKE '%93%%';
 ?column? 
══════════
 t
(1 row)

test=> SELECT 'above 93.15% or not' LIKE '%93\%%';
WARNING:  nonstandard use of escape in a string literal
LINE 1: SELECT 'above 93.15% or not' LIKE '%93\%%';
                                          ^
HINT:  Use the escape string syntax for escapes, e.g., E'\r\n'.
 ?column? 
══════════
 t
(1 row)

test=> SELECT 'above 93.15% or not' LIKE '%93\\%%';
WARNING:  nonstandard use of \\ in a string literal
LINE 1: SELECT 'above 93.15% or not' LIKE '%93\\%%';
                                          ^
HINT:  Use the escape string syntax for backslashes, e.g., E'\\'.
 ?column? 
══════════
 f
(1 row)

test=> SELECT 'above 93.15% or not' LIKE '%93\\\%%';
WARNING:  nonstandard use of \\ in a string literal
LINE 1: SELECT 'above 93.15% or not' LIKE '%93\\\%%';
                                          ^
HINT:  Use the escape string syntax for backslashes, e.g., E'\\'.
 ?column? 
══════════
 f
(1 row)
```